# adding buttons in gridlayout programmatically and set width and heigth in percentage

Tags: c#, android, layout, android-gridlayout

I have a method that creates Buttons with fix size of width and height. To create the Buttons I am using a layout.xaml template. The button template will be called by the command :

```
var btn = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.btn, null);
```

During the method the buttons get special text and Color. On the end of the button customization the button will be added to the gridlayout with following code:

```
var pari = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(widthbutton, heightbutton)
RunOnUiThread(() => gridlayout.AddView(val.Value, pari));
```

widthbutton and heightbutton is just a fix number.
My Question is: I want to set the width and heigth of the buttons depending on the size of the gridlayout. So, how do I set the size of the buttons in percentage?

Comment: if you want to resize them according to the screen size, try to use "Padding" . use "wrap_content" for height and width. Don't give accurate numbers so it will not resize them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match your buttons to your GridLayout width and Height, you can use **match_parent** to match the height and width of gridLayout.
So, it will be like...

```
var pari = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0.5f);
```

The constructor RelativeLayout is passing is the weight, 0.5f means half of the allocated room for your instance. Controlling this will allow you to control both the width and height of the UI component.

Then add it to your UI. Cheers

**EDITED**

Here is how you actually add a relative layout in your UI

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT....... );
```

**my question..** 
what does **var pari** actually hold? If it is a non-ui component (Not RelativeLayout type), then you cannot actually add it to your UI. I actually gave the previous solution/suggestion thinking you might be aware of this. 
Anyway, to keeping away from further assumption, perhaps it will be best to see the errors first :) 
Cheers

Comment: Any idea : Why I can not use LayoutParams ?

Answer (score 0):

@ibtehaz: pari holds a relativelayout which has customized textView in it. This relativelayout will be inflated by the method called by the OnCreate method. After I define my buttons with information I do now change the padding of the relativelayout and I get e.g. a grid showing 4*4 (rows\columns) which is what I want.  The padding can be modified by :

```
btn.SetPadding(10, 18, 10, 18);
```

It is still not that solution I initially wanted but for the moment it does what it should. Thanks to all for your help